# infinite-scroll not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am using `InfiniteScroll` that in the link from binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

```
 <div id="cardsDiv"  infinite-scroll="getMoreCards()" infinite-scroll-distance="2">       
 </div>
```

when `infinite-scroll-distance="2"` the function working on start at desktop  without touching the scroll and in mobile working perfect

when `infinite-scroll-distance="1"`  mobile not working at all and desktop working perfect

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation ([link](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html)).

> infinite-scroll-distance (optional) - {number} - A number representing how close the bottom of the element must be to the bottom of the browser window before the expression specified by infinite-scroll is triggered. Measured in multiples of the window height; for example, if the browser window is 1000 pixels tall and infinite-scroll-distance is set to 2, the infinite scroll expression will be evaluated when the bottom of the element is within 2000 pixels of the bottom of the browser window. Defaults to 0 (e.g. the expression will be evaluated when the bottom of the element crosses the bottom of the browser window).

So since you gave it value "2", on desktop (assuming you have a full HD monitor), it will start scrolling immediately. Similar scenario with mobile.

Simple solution would be to set it to "0" and hope that this would work well every time. Or else you could try this:

```
var getInfScrollDist = function() {
    var winWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    return winWidth > 420 ? 1 : 2;
};

$window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    $scope.infScrollDist = getInfScrollDist();
}, false);

$scope.infScrollDist = getInfScrollDist();
```

In template:

```
<div id="cardsDiv" infinite-scroll="getMoreCards()" infinite-scroll-distance="infScrollDist"></div>
```

**P.S:** Don't forget to remove the listener on `$window` when the `$scope` is destroyed:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $window.removeEventListener( 'resize' );
});
```

Comment: is there js library that do all that and take care all screens without  me doing it myself?

Comment: Sorry mate, I can't help you there. Never created infinite scrolls with Angular.